# Adding Completer ui file

Tags: pyqt4, qcompleter

I have created a form in Py Qt Designer with the filename xyz.ui. As in the attached image the highlighted field is QLineEdit. I want to attach QCompleter auto completion functionality to that field, can someone tell me how to do that. I have got the solutions on net but those are for standalone Gui not for any existing ui file.

[image]

Comment: The solutions should be exactly the same. What makes you think they would be any different? Have you tried any of them, and if so, what went wrong?

Comment: I got the solution and you are right it should work in the similar manner. But there is a caveat. I was developing this form for QGIS plugin, and it handles String in a different manner than PyQt. https://hub.qgis.org/wiki/17/Python_plugin_API_changes_from_18_to_20. I was using QString() and QStringList for the implementation as normal QLineEdit, but in QGIS the strings has to be intered as list. They are not read as QStringList.